# How to undo javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a function like so which toggles my dropdown menu.

```
<div class="module widget-handle mobile-toggle right visible-sm visible-xs">
  <a id="mobile-nav" href="#">
    <div class="container1" onclick="myFunction(this)">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>.
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<script>
  function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle('change');
    document.body.style.overflow ='hidden'
  }
</script>
```

The last part of it

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
```

Keeps the page from overflowing at the top when the dropdown menu is open. The problem is that when I click on my menu bars, whilst the overflow disappears, clicking on the bars again reveals the page but locks it due to the overflow being hidden.

I'd like to undo

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'
```

When the menu is closed and the closest I've got to understanding it is the function `doBack`. Can I somehow add `doBack` to my existing function?

Mobile page [here](https://4309.co.uk)

It's a WordPress site and the javascript above toggles the dropdown by pressing on the bars. In order to extend the dropdown, I made the class `collapse` bigger, like so.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .collapse {
    position: absolute;
    height: 775px;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 99999 !important;
    top: 75px;
    left: -50px;
    line-height: 10px;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="module-group right">
  <div class="module left">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul id="menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-15050" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-15050 dropdown">
          <a title="Contact" href="url">Contact
            <ul role="menu" class="dropdow n-menu">
            </ul>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the style attribute by using:

```
document.body.style.overflow = null
```

Comment: Thanks. The thing is I want the style, just not when i close the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a new CSS class:

```
.body-overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

and in your javascript function add another `.classList.toggle()` but this time on the body:

```
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle('change');
  document.body.classList.toggle('body-overflow');
}
```

Comment: thanks but didn't work. If you look here the page is still overflowing at the top when I open my menu https://4309.co.uk/drawing

Comment: The thing is that i don't have a class called `body-overflow`. have i misunderstood something about classlist. Toggle?

Comment: @Stacksof99, I know you don't have it I just provided the CSS class above to include it in your CSS, if you have access to CSS and can modify it just add it and add the js code I provided, then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts but I tried and didn't work.